# primefaces datatable width not rendering good

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable, responsive-design

When I use a datatable and start shrinking my browser window, the datatable has a weird behavior. The center part (where the data is), doesn't shrink but the paginator does.

Here are some pics about the problem.

Thanks in advance.[image: Normal behavior][image: Problem]

Answer (score 0):

It's because it can't break up the titles in your table header. If you would place spaces in between instead of using capital letters, it would break the title up and divide it over multiple lines.

If you don't have access to the table header's name (or the ability to change it), take a look at the **[word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)**-property in CSS.